# Deserialize JSON Array to List

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I tried the solution available but i am still not able to print the list
Here is my JSON

```
var result = [
    {
        "id": 1409636
    },
    {
        "id": 1499272
    },
    {
        "id": 1409587
    },
    {
        "id": 1409588
    },
    {
        "id": 1409589
    }
]
```

This is the code i have

```
public class stgmd
{
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
}

List<stgmd> resultlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<stgmd>>(result);


foreach (var results in resultlist)
{
    Console.WriteLine(results);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Suggestions??

Comment: You've made an edit that completely changes your question (and invalidates the existing answers).  What is your _actual_ code?  What is the _actual_ value of `result`?  Your "json" isnt actually json, its a javascript array initializer, if that is the string you are trying to deserialize then you will have problems

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the edit is the actual code , but the value of the result is from an Web API output. I want to convert the output to a list of integer for further processing.

Comment: your code doesn't compile.

Comment: instead of `Console.WriteLine(results)`, use `Console.WriteLine(results.id)` if it is that that you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

stageid and id does not match. You either need to do:

```
public class stgmd
{
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class stgmd
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public Int64 stageid { get; set; }
}
```

Edit regarding your comment:

If your JSON really starts with `var result=` that is wrong. Your JSON should be a string containing something like

```
[
 {
    "id": 1409636
},
{
    "id": 1499272
 },
 {
    "id": 1409587
 },
 {
    "id": 1409588
 },
 {
    "id": 1409589
 }
]
```

and nothing more.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the JSON message before posting and hence the discrepancy. I changed property now. But it still would not print the list

Comment: If my edit doesn't help either (as your last comment shows it probably won't) please get the actual value of "result" using the debugger. And also describe more accurately what "I am still not able to print the list" means. Does it enter the loop and just doesn't print anything or is your parsed list empty? Also add an [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the json name for the property via `JsonProperty`:

```
[JsonProperty("id")]
public int stageid { get; set; }
```

Comment: actually i edited the json message before posting. I corrected it. Its does not work